# I'm trying to write code that will check in the browsers local storage and see if there is a key or an object with the key of user

Tags: angular, observable

I'm new to angular, I'm getting the error "**Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.**", when I try to write the code that checks if there is an object or a key with the key of user in the browser's localstorage. [Here's a screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYtYI.png)

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { error } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AccountService } from '_services/account.service';
    import { User } from './_models/user';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      title = 'High';
      users :any;
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private accountService: AccountService) {  }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.getUsers();
        this.setCurrentUser();
      }
    
      setCurrentUser()
      {
        const user : User  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        this.accountService.setCurrentUser(user);
      }
    
      getUsers()
      {
        this.http.get('https://localhost:5001/api/users').subscribe(response =>
        {
          this.users = response;
        },
        error =>
        {
          console.log(error);
        })
      }
      
    }
```

**accountService.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { User } from 'src/app/_models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {
  baseUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/api/';
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User |null>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(model: any) {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', model).pipe(
      map((response: User) => {
        const user = response;
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
      });
    )
  }

  setCurrentUser(user: User) {
    this.currentUserSource.next(user);
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    this.currentUserSource.next(null);
  }
}
```

**user.ts**

```
export interface User {
    username: string ;
    token: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

localStorage.getItem can either return you a string or null and hence the the type inference is (string | null). And since JSON.parse accepts only string, you see that error by TS compiler.

You can modify your function like this:

```
setCurrentUser() {
     const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
     if(user) {
         this.accountService.setCurrentUser(JSON.parse(user));
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The program is not actually run, so local storage might be getting null.
Do this in your current

```
setCurrentUser()
    {
      **const user : User  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')||'');**
      this.accountService.setCurrentUser(user);
    }
```

Do these changes in all places where you are trying to get the data from local storage.